# Python read office mail without outlook client

Tags: python, python-3.x, imaplib, webmail

I've to read email without using outlook client installed.

My client's webmail initially goes to [Login.microsoft.com](http://Login.microsoft.com) before redirected to actual login page of the company.

## IMAP4/POP3

I tried to initially read using IMAP4/POP3 like below:

```
import imaplib
import email

# Connect to an IMAP server
def connect(server, user, password):
    m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(server)
    m.login(user, password)
    m.select()
    return m
```

On trying to login getting login failed. There is nothing wrong with the server/username/password. I am not good at IAMP4/POP3 settings. May be it was not enabled :(

## ASMX webservice

I could find out that ews can be accessed by https://webmail.company.org/ews/exchange.asmx. Again, I could not be successful to access web methods. I may also have to do delete email functionality in future.

## Office 365 REST API

I started reading about accessing using office 365. But, I need Client ID and secret key, which I don't have

I would like to know how to connect my webmail using python without having outlook installed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is likely that your organization has not enabled IMAP access to the Exchange message store. As far as I know it is switched off by default. You need to talk to your sysops about this.

Comment: @BoarGules Sysops team will not enable IMAP. Is there any other way I can access email without outlook client installed and with the current settings of mail server?

Comment: I rather thought they might not. If you need Office 365 credentials.then you will need to ask your client to arrange them.

Comment: @boarglues Thanls for the information. I will try to get the details. But chances are very thin. So, there is no other way of accessing, right?

Comment: I'm afraid not. By default, access to the Exchange message store is comprehensively locked down because of potential security and stability risks.

Comment: Okay sure. This gives me confidence to say it is not possible without having office 365 details. Thanks for your time and information

Comment: Generally, you need to implement Microsoft OAUTH variant, ADAL.  They even have a python library https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries.  You will also need to register your application with Microsoft to get a client id and secret.

Comment: Hi Max, I read about registering the application. Unfortunately, my client is not ready to do that. Thanks for the information